# jQuery addEventListener + ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, addeventlistener

I have a problem, my jQuery function doesn't work. It's initialize (alert before addEventListener works, but the click is not detected. 
The tricks works with a

```
onclick="attachEventsFid2()"
```

But not with my code :

```
function attachEventsFid2() {
    var main=$('.main-wrapper');
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn-iphone4");

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:BASE_URL+'index/formfid2/',
            data:{'iphone':iphone},
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
            main.parent().html(data);    
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Html part :

```
<div class="row row3">
<a id="btn-iphone5" class="ico-reserver choix-iphone"  type="button" value="iphone5"  ></a>
</div>
```

Logs :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

With getElementsByClassName i have an other log :

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (=>
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) { ... )
```

Thanks !

Comment: where is the portion that is problematic?

Comment: The addEvenListener function (don't work neither with a click() )

Comment: post your html as well

Comment: Which jquery library you are using? please post your html head part also.

Comment: jQuery v1.7.1 @JitendraPancholi

Comment: @lovis91: What was the error?

Comment: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @JitendraPancholi u have an idea ?

Comment: Please put your compete html and javascript because the code snippet you posted above is working in fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it working.

```
function attachEventsFid2() {
    var main=$('.main-wrapper');
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn-iphone4");

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('clicked');
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    attachEventsFid2();
});

<input type="button" id="btn-iphone4" value="click"/>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wwb57/2/

FYI: your provided code is also working. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wwb57/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:BASE_URL+'index/formfid2/',
        data:{'iphone':iphone},
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
        main.parent().html(data);    
        }
    });
});
```

Try that, just use "on" ;)

If your alert works before that should be great

Comment: same problem.. the alert works before but not on click.. Very strange i edit for the html part

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mixing jQuery and JS-plain so much? Use jQuery for the event binding ... and call you function some where:

```
function attachEventsFid2() {
    var main= $('.main-wrapper');
    var btn = $("#btn-iphone4");

    btn.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:BASE_URL+'index/formfid2/',
            data:{'iphone':iphone},
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
            main.parent().html(data);    
            }
        });
    });
};
//Call it...
attachEventsFid2();
```